# How to attach form data in url which is used by Ajax?

Tags: javascript, ajax, url

So, I came across this problem whereby I want to access the data of a website, but it works only after the user interacts with the website. So, after selecting the date, it sends the ajax request to its site with a url, but also the form data. Here is the screenshot taken in Google Chrome. 
[image]

And the problem is, the url doesn't work without specifying the cdate parameter as highlighted in the picture. Is there any way, I can send the form data (cdate in our case) to the specified url, so that it doesn't lead me to the error? Any way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

In order to send form data progmatically, you can use the `FormData` object like so:

```
var formData = new FormData();

formData.append("cdate", "09/14/2019");

var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("POST", "http://example.com");
request.send(formData);
request.onLoad => (e) {
   // Do something with request.response
};
```

Adapted from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects